# how i can attach country identification script to my signup page and make if statments?

Tags: php, html

i made a group box of three countries us,uk,ca of their states so the problem i don't know how to make the page show the apropreiate groupbox of states to the signer (i mean when a signer is from canada it must appear to him a list of canada provinces same for the us one and the uk one), so obviuosly i don't know how to attach the script to my signup page 
ps: am not that good in php so please guys if u can explain in details if possible that would be great

```
    <?php

    $IPaddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    $two_letter_country_code=iptocountry("$IPaddress");

    function iptocountry($ip) {   
    $numbers = preg_split( "/\./", $ip);   
    include("ip_files/0.php");
include("ip_files/1.php");
include("ip_files/2.php");
    $code=($numbers[0] * 16777216) + ($numbers[1] * 65536) + ($numbers[2] * 256) + ($numbers[3]);   
    foreach($ranges as $key => $value){
    if($key<=$code){
        if($ranges[$key][0]>=$code){$country=$ranges[$key][1];break;}
        }
    }
    if ($country==""){$country="unkown";}
    return $country;

     }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the hostinfo API. http://www.hostip.info/use.html.

```
http_GET('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=12.215.42.19'.$ip);
```

returns the country id (e.g. 'US' for America)

Put this inside `<?php  ?>` within your `<select>` element.
Then, once you've identified the country, use an array of the states, and loop through it adding the option elements to the select node:

```
switch ($country) {
case "US":
$states = array("state1", "state2" );
    break;
case "UK":
....
}
foreach($states as $state) 
{
   $state = htmlspecialchars($state);
   echo '<option value="'. $state .'">'. $state .'</option>';
}
```

Here's an example - you'll need to put the country code generator in your code yourself though (I don't have the nessecary `i_files`):http://pastebin.com/pTpEStHj

Working example (sample country code):http://fotest.co.nf/index%20-%20Copy.html

Comment: but that doesn't answer my question :/ and the problem isn't in the identification

Comment: sorry - misread the question - If you're able to get the country, you could use an array of the states, and then loop through the array with a `foreach` to add the option elements. I'll add the code in a minute.

Comment: hum it's not exactly that  but thank you so much for your help i appréciate that

Comment: okey look i made a signup page in englich and in that signup page i didn't make copy for each country i just made different details for the appropreiate country like the groupbox of states like for canada i made a groupbox canada's provinces and for us same thing also for uk and for identification i use the script above (works well) so the problem i don't know how  to make the signup page show the apropreiate box of states to signer i mean when a signer will signup is canadian he will find only only canada provinces not included us & uk ones

Comment: so in fact it's just a matter of if statement and how to attach the script above with the signup page so that the if statement will be excuted nicely

Comment: This actually sounds like the type of thing which might be more easily accomplished using javascript, since you've already got html. You could use an xmlhttp request to an ip geolocator, and then display the appropriate <select>.

Comment: yeah that's a good idee to use java but is there anyway to do it only in php cause am near to get it but i don't know where is the problem anyway thank you sir for your time :)

Comment: This should work now - you can set the country however you want

Comment: oh sorry you posted it here well sorry i will try it now and i'll tell u so u saw the script in the new question ?

Comment: I saw the new script - does it return the correct country for you?

Comment: yeah it does but the problem is just i don't f know how to attach -_-

Comment: I've tested, and my code is able to set the contents of the select - what form is `$country` in? You may need to edit the switch statement.

Comment: it is a country code two letters and i used you code but i got a blank page oh god if it worked for u please give me the whole script am tiered of this

Comment: Was the pastebin of any help?

Comment: nope didn't work and beside that if the result is as u showed it's not that :( look bro am hyper tired i need to sleep if possible please keep an eye to this post when i get up we will continue if u want of caurse see ya bro and thank u so much